# Slow parallelizing of network-bound I/O when timeouts occur

Tags: c#, plinq

I am parallelizing a method that highly relies on WinAPI NetAPI32 calls. The calls sometimes timeout if the user entered a host that is down or several in a list of hundreds.

```
int prevThreads, prevPorts;
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out prevThreads, out prevPorts);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(20, prevPorts);

var parallelScanList = computersToScan.AsParallel().WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism).WithDegreeOfParallelism(20);

Api.WinApi.AdvApi.LogonAndImpersonate(connection.UserCredential);

foreach (var computer in parallelScanList)
{
        //...
        //this takes a long time to timeout
        status = NetApi.NetUserEnum(computer.DnsHostname, 2,
                (int)NetApi.NetUserEnumFilter.FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT,
                out userbufPtr, (int)LmCons.MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out userEntriesRead, out totalEntries,
                out userResumeHandle);

}
```

We have similar logic to this in a C client using a consumer/producer.  Spin up 20 threads and have them read a list until it's depleted.

```
function StartProcessingHosts()
{
  for 1 to 20
     StartProcessThread()
}

function ProcessHostsThread()
{
  while(moreHosts)
  {
     //obviously synchronization around here
     var host = popHost();
     DoSomething(host);
  }
}
```

And that's very fast because of all the waiting going on with these network calls and the possibility of being unable to connect to a downed host.

The way I'm currently doing it in C# seems to be doing it one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLINQ, short for Parallel LINQ is for, you guessed it, *parallelizing LINQ queries*. For example, if you write `collection.AsParallel().Where(/* some condition */).Select(/* some projection */).ToList()`, then the `Where()` and `Select()` will execute in parallel.

But you don't do that, you call `AsParallel()`, saying "the following LINQ query should execute in parallel". Then you configure the parallelism of the upcoming query by calling `WithExecutionMode()` and `WithDegreeOfParallelism()`. And then you don't actually have any LINQ query, instead you use `foreach`, which will iterate the collection serially.

If you want to execute a `foreach` in parallel, you don't want PLINQ, you want `Parallel.ForEach()`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(computersToScan, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 },
    computer =>
    {
        //...
    });
```

Comment: @Bluebaron There is, [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747).

Comment: Yup.  Figured it out.  You are the winner.  Thanks!

Comment: -1 I/O bound parallelization should not be done with threads. Firstly, because threads are a precious resource and by creating 20 of them, you are wasting memory and thread synchronization time. Secondly because it doesn't make it faster, because the bottleneck is in the Socket creation, and that isn't speed up by having multiple threads. Windows by default will limit the rate of socket creation against the same host. This SHOULD be done as an asynchronous single thread, and controlling the creation of the sockets (possibly reusing them).

Comment: @Aron So what's the asynchronous version of `NetUserEnum()`? I couldn't find any.

Comment: @Aron Also: 1. Sometimes, convenience is worth some memory and context switches. 2. Do you have more information about that limit? I know about `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`, but that should not be relevant when using Win32 API directly. 3. I think each request is to a different computer, so that limit shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Aron, the problem is there is no asynchronous way to call this function.  Spinning up multiple threads helps a lot because this is mostly I/O-bound and those threads have to wait .. a lot.  In fact, the speed up is n/m | {m=number of threads}.  The overhead of creating threads is unnoticeable because of the slowness of the api call.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I see, the issue is the foreach loop. You have probably assumed that by making the query `AsParallel` and then executing it in foreach will make it parallel. Of course that won't happen. Also, using PLINQ you can achieve the same as demonstrated in [svick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35690036/1835769).

However, here is another way to parallelize your code and I mention it below because svick's answer too suffers from the fact that just by setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20` you do not guarantee 20 parallel executions. It still is only the upper limit of parallel execution, not a lower limit. If PLINQ execution engine feels that it should start only 5 parallel executions, it will start only 5 and that is completely legal execution.

The following code guarantees 20 parallel executions:

```
var concurrentScanList = new ConcurrentQueue<Computer>(computersToScan);
var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
var taskArray = new Task[20];

//Initializing the tasks
for (var index = 0; index < taskArray.Length; index++)
{
    taskArray[index] = taskFactory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Computer host;
        while (concurrentScanList.TryDequeue(out host))
        {
            DoSomething(host);
        }
    });
}

//Wait for all tasks to finish - queue will be empty then
Task.WaitAll(baseProcessorTaskArray);
```

---

**Old Answer:**

[`WithDegreeOfParallelism()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383719(v=vs.100).aspx) is,

> the maximum number of concurrently executing tasks that will be used to process the query.

...and it's my thought that since the minimum number of concurrently executing tasks is not fixed, it might be 1.

Essentially, your guess may be right that this execution is not happening in parallel and therefore timing out. Further, even if it *is* happening in parallel with a degree of parallelism equal to 20, it is not guaranteed to be this way always.

My suggestion would be that you put the "computers to scan" in a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) and then spawn 20 tasks which read a computer each from this BlockingCollection and then scan it. This implementation will naturally be *Producer Consumer* because that's an intrinsic quality of your problem's design.

Comment: `WithDegreeOfParallelism()` only affects parallel queries, but there isn't one in the shown code.

Comment: @svick: I get it. Updated.